# Not able to load English language module of spacy with spacy.load('en')

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I am not able to load the English model in jupyter notebook with below code-

```
!pip install spacy
import spacy
spacy.load('en')
```

Error message:

> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 spacy.load('en')
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy_*init*_.py in
> load(name, **overrides)
> 19     if depr_path not in (True, False, None):
> 20         deprecation_warning(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path))
> ---> 21     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
> 22
> 23
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in
> load_model(name, **overrides)
> 117     elif hasattr(name, 'exists'):  # Path or Path-like to model data
> 118         return load_model_from_path(name, **overrides)
> --> 119     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
> 120
> 121
>
> OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a
> shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

I have installed python version **2.7.15**, **3.6.7**, **3.7.1** and **Anaconda3 5.3.1**

I have downloaded the spacy package with

> ```
> !pip install spacy
> ```

and English package with

> ```
> python -m spacy download en
> ```

in anaconda prompt

Comment: Well, and which of the many Python versions are you using actually? Can you reduce your problem, e.g. to a simple script that can be started from the commandline?

Answer (score 8):

Edit: Based on your comments it seems you downloaded the model but couldn't link it. You do not have permission to do it, check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user/125981#125981) and give permission to current user. After that download model with same script:

```
python -m spacy download en
```

Check [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1283#issuecomment-323981358), there is a brief description of the error.

Comment: Thanks for your input I have tried but gives below error-

Requirement already satisfied: en_core_web_sm==2.0.0 from https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm==2.0.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.0.0)

    Linking successful
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm -->
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en

    You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')

You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.

Comment: Hm it's interesting, maybe you downloaded but not linked. While you are downloading the language did you face with this kind of error ? `You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.`

Comment: No, I did not face any error. While using spacy.load('en') I faced the error "You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation."

Comment: it shows the invalid syntax

  File "<ipython-input-6-fc4d5d118d23>", line 1
    python -m spacy download en
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Did you run it in notebook? If you running a command in notebook you need to add `!` char to head of command like :`!python -m spacy download en`

Comment: Yes, I run it in the notebook. I have tried with "!"  and it gives the error seen in the 1st comment and if I try without "!" then it shows error reported in 3rd comment.

Comment: Why I got error `OSError: [E049] Can't find spaCy data directory: 'None'. Check your installation and permissions, or use spacy.util.set_data_path to customise the location if necessary.`?

Answer (score 3):

I installed Spyder and anoconda which allowed me to run spacy but only in Spyder. Try that to see if you can run from there.

**Update**

Try using the following instead

```
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download en
```

The use this in your code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I'm using anaconda with windows. I solved it by following below steps.
Run anaconda prompt or command prompt as administrator and then run below commands.

`pip install spacy python -m spacy download en`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, it could be that you have downloaded spacy model but symbolic link is failing. No worries, you can copy paste the folder manually to get it detected.

1. Go to site-packages of your python.
2. See the package you downloaded, for my case it was **en_core_web_sm**
3. Copy and rename it to ../site-packages/spacy/data/en

Answer (score 0):

Running anaconda prompt as an admin before installing any package solves all the problems. This way I did not have to double install modules using either pip3 or conda.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt or terminal and execute the below code:

`pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0/en_core_web_sm-2.2.0.tar.gz`

Execute the below chunk in your Jupiter notebook.

`import spacy`

`nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`

Hope the above code works for all:)

Answer (score 0):

I was building a script which uses spacy, but as I deploy this on dataproc clusters which are provisioned everytime, the spacy models won't be downloaded by default. So what I did was trying to import the model, if it isn't downloaded, download & load it.

```
def load_spacy_model(model_name):
    excluded_steps = ["tagger", "parser", "ner", "entitiy_linker", 
                      "entity_ruler", "textcat", "morphologizer",
                      "attribute_ruler", "senter", "sentencizer", 
                      "token2vec", "transformer"]
    try:
        spacy_model = spacy.load(model_name, exclude=excluded_steps)
    except OSError:
        spacy.cli.download(model_name)
        spacy_model = spacy.load(model_name, exclude=excluded_steps)
    return spacy_model
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only this;

*import spacy*

*nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")*

**here 'en' in 'en_core_web_sm' means "English".**

For Windows Python Install, You don't need to use this;

nlp = spacy.load('en')  # Just delete it or comment it.

If you go to SpaCy documentation page;
https://spacy.io/usage/models

when you change Language dropdown list selection to other language, the syntax of;
"nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')" will change automatically according to your selection.
For example, for Franch Language(after import spacy) the syntax will be;

*nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")*