# I am facing error while running spacy code

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-transformers

```
# load the model
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# check the same string with spaCy
string = "Our Deeds are the Reason of this #earthquake May ALLAH Forgive us all"
print([(token.text, token.pos_) for token in nlp(string) if token.pos_=='PROPN'])
```

I am trying to run this code and I am getting below error.

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17348\4216200013.py in <module>
      1 # load the model
----> 2 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
      3 
      4 # check the same string with spaCy
      5 string = "Our Deeds are the Reason of this #earthquake May ALLAH Forgive us all"

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in load(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
     52     RETURNS (Language): The loaded nlp object.
     53     """
---> 54     return util.load_model(
     55         name,
     56         vocab=vocab,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py in load_model(name, vocab, disable, enable, exclude, config)
    437     if name in OLD_MODEL_SHORTCUTS:
    438         raise IOError(Errors.E941.format(name=name, full=OLD_MODEL_SHORTCUTS[name]))  # type: ignore[index]
--> 439     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
    440 
    441 

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to load English language module of spacy with spacy.load('en')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911615/not-able-to-load-english-language-module-of-spacy-with-spacy-loaden)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't downloaded the English pipeline. Try running:

```
spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Comment: Please share with me whole procedure

Comment: Please see the official installation instructions. You run `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` after installing the library. (The `python -m` part is usually not required but sometimes the command won't work without it.) https://spacy.io/usage